# return the download URL of a file uploaded to firebase

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-storage, snapshot

Is there a simple way to get the download URL of a file uploaded to Firebase?

(I've tried playing around with the snapshot returned by my upload function and couldn't find anything...)

```
     fileref.put(file).then(function(snapshot){
     self.addEntry(snapshot);   
     ///  return snapshot.url???
     });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the Url created by default from the snapshot you can use `downloadURL`, meaning  `snapshot.downloadURL`.

Remember to always keep tracking the progress of the upload by using `.on('state_changed')`, [Documentation here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/web/upload-files#sube_archivos).

Comment: The documentation referenced here uses the function `snapshot.ref.getDownloadURL().then(downloadURL)` to get a reference to the download URL, it doesn't simply access a property on the snapshot object.

Comment: snapshot.downloadURL is deprecated use snapshot.ref.getDownloadURL() instead

Answer (score 22):

The documentation referenced by Yamil - [Firebase javascript SDK file upload](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/web/upload-files#sube_archivos) - recommends using the snapshot's `ref` property to invoke the `getDownloadURL` method, which returns a promise containing the download link:

Using your code as a starting point:

```
fileref.put(file)
   .then(snapshot => {
       return snapshot.ref.getDownloadURL();   // Will return a promise with the download link
   })

   .then(downloadURL => {
      console.log(`Successfully uploaded file and got download link - ${downloadURL}`);
      return downloadURL;
   })

   .catch(error => {
      // Use to signal error if something goes wrong.
      console.log(`Failed to upload file and get link - ${error}`);
   });
```

I know it seems like unnecessary effort and that you should be able to get the link via a property of the snapshot, but this is what the Firebase team recommends - they probably have a good reason for doing it this way.

Answer (score -2):

When using user based security rules as given [in official docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/security/user-security)

// Only an individual user can write to "their" images

```
  match /{userId}/{imageId} {
    allow write: if request.auth.uid == userId;
  }
```

url retrieved by snapshot.downloadURL is exposing userId. How to overcome this security risk.

Comment: If you write your storage & database security rules correctly there is no risk in exposing user ID. Also, this should be another question (it already exists I believe), not as a question under different question.