# firebase snapshot.downloadURL is undefined after successfully uploading an image

Tags: firebase, firebase-storage, angularfire, snapshot

I have this code in my app, that I use to upload an image and get its url so that i can save it in the database, the image is in base64 format and the upload is successfull as i can see in `console.log(snapshot);` output, and by checking also in my firebase storage however, the downloadUrl property of snapshot is undefined i dont know why.  This is not the way it was supposed to work

```
storage.$putString(b64, 'data_url', {contentType:'image/jpg'}).$complete(function(snapshot) {
        console.log(snapshot);
        item.avatarUrl=snapshot.downloadURL;
        agents.$add(item).then(function(ref) {
        });

    });
```

Comment: Getting the download URL nowadays requires an extra roundtrip. See for an example this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43911080/return-the-download-url-of-a-file-uploaded-to-firebase/50448571#50448571

Answer (score 6):

Use `snapshot.ref.getDownloadURL()`

Comment: This now returns a promise. See nadir's answer.

Answer (score 4):

**Novomber 2019 update** from the official documentation of **firebase** :

```
function(){
      uploadTask.snapshot.ref.getDownloadURL().then(function(downloadURL) {
        console.log('File available at', downloadURL);
      });

    });
```

[Here is the source from firebase documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/web/upload-files)

Answer (score 0):

I am using angularfire2 5.0.0-rc11 and facing the same issue. I modified the code as follows:

```
storage.$putString(b64, 'data_url', {contentType:'image/jpg'}).$complete(function(snapshot) {
    console.log(snapshot);
    //item.avatarUrl=snapshot.downloadURL;
      // changed to:
      snapshot.getDownloadURL()
      .then( downloadUrl => {

        item.avatarUrl=downloadUrl
        agents.$add(item).then(function(ref) {
        });
      })
      .catch( error => {
        console.log(error);
        //catch error here
      });

});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Andorid, use this code to get uploaded File Uri.

```
Task<Uri> downloadUrl = taskSnapshot.getMetadata().getReference().getDownloadUrl(); 
Uri fileUri = downloadUrl.getResult().toString();
```