# How to store image in firebase storage and save the image url in realtime database

Tags: javascript, html, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-storage

I got Undefined Url. Someone know how to solve my problem?

```
function store(){
    var litrato = this.files[0];

    var storageref = firebase.storage().ref('gallery/' + litrato.name);
    var uploadTask = storageref.put(litrato);
    uploadTask.on('state_changed', function(snapshot){
    }, function(error){
    }, function(){
        var downloadURL = uploadTask.snapshot.downloadURL;
        console.log(downloadURL);
    });
}
```

Comment: The `downloadURL` property is no longer available on the snapshot. You'll need to call `getDownloadURL()` on the `StorageReference` once the upload completes. For an example of this: https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/web/upload-files#monitor_upload_progress

Comment: Also see https://stackoverflow.com/q/53231025, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43911080/return-the-download-url-of-a-file-uploaded-to-firebase/50448571#50448571

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The download URL is no longer available on the task snapshot that you use to monitor the upload task. Instead you need to call `getDownloadURL()` on the `StorageReference` once the upload has completed. See the sample in the documentation on [monitoring upload progress](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/web/upload-files#monitor_upload_progress). Applied to your code, this becomes:

```
var storageref = firebase.storage().ref('gallery/' + litrato.name);
var uploadTask = storageref.put(litrato);
uploadTask.on('state_changed', function(snapshot){
}, function(error){
  console.error(error);
}, function() {
  uploadTask.snapshot.ref.getDownloadURL().then(function(downloadURL) {
    console.log('File available at', downloadURL);
  });
});
```

Comment: Thank you sir how about retrieving back the image In the web Like in the div?

Comment: That seems to be a different problem, but if you just create an `img` and set its `src` attribute then it should show up. Something like `var img = document.createElement('img'); img.src = downloadURL; document.body.appendChild(img);`.